# CKeditor 4 plugin button doesn't appear

Tags: ckeditor, drupal-8

I have a working extention plugin (myplugin) which extends the drupalimagecaption plugin, which extends drupalimage which extend the original image plugin. Now I want to add an additional toolbar button to myplugin plugin. Here is how I try to add:

```
(function (CKEDITOR) {

  'use strict';

  CKEDITOR.plugins.add('myplugin', {
    icons: 'drupalimage,DoubleImage',
    requires: 'drupalimagecaption',
    hidpi: true,

    beforeInit: function (editor) {
      // [...] Here are some overwrites

      var imageSaveCallback = function (data) {
        editor.fire('saveSnapshot');
        var content = data.image_render;
        editor.insertHtml(content);
        editor.fire('saveSnapshot');
      };

      // Implementation before initializing plugin.
      editor.addCommand('InsertDoubleImage', {
        canUndo: true,
        exec: function (editor, data) {
          Drupal.ckeditor.openDialog(editor,
            Drupal.url('mydrupalmodule/dialog/double_image/' + editor.config.drupal.format),
            {},
            imageSaveCallback,
            {}
          );
        }
      });

      // Register the toolbar button.
      if (editor.ui.addButton) {
        editor.ui.addButton('DoubleImage', {
          label: Drupal.t('Upload Double Image'),
          command: 'InsertDoubleImage'
        });
      }
    }
  });

})(CKEDITOR);
```

My main problem is, some why this button doesn't appear on the drupal's admin UI, so I'm not able to add to the CKeditor's toolbar. I also has a PHP class which loads this file (where this script lives) and I define there too the new and the current button:

```
public function getButtons() {
  return [
    'DrupalImage' => array(
      'label' => t('Single Image Popup'),
      'image' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mydrupalmodule') . '/js/plugins/elevation/icons/drupalimage.png',
    ),
    'DoubleImage' => array(
      'label' => t('Double Image Popup'),
      'image' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mydrupalmodule') . '/js/plugins/elevation/icons/DoubleImage.png',
    ),
  ];
}
```

Actually I don't know what am I missing and I can't find why doesn't want to work... (only the overwrite work, but the button doesn't appear...) It's not possible to add new button if you overwrite an existing plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fount the problem. If I want to create a plugin for CKeditor in Drupal 8 I need to extend the `CKEditorPluginBase` not the `PluginBase` class. They extend the `PluginBase` in the `DrupalImageCaption` class (which I used as the base), but this won't work in my case.